# Is there deployment trigger for teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

I know there are build triggers. But do deployment triggers exist in team city? I googled quite a bit and looked at the doc and cannot seem to find it. I basically want custom code to check few things before deploying. But it needs to happen from team city's deploy page.

Comment: Deployment triggers would mean that the build will trigger on deployment of something (VCS trigger fires when VCS change is detected, Schedule trigger fires on particular time). I guess this is not what you want. If you want custom code to check something you can include it in a separate step and in next step you can do a deployment. By default second step won't execute if first step will fail.

Comment: Looks like deployment triggers are similar to build triggers. Teamcity deployment task can have any custom code to execute.

Comment: There is no `deployment trigger` - you can find a list of build triggers here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Triggers Please describe in more details what you want to achieve. Of course, TC build configuration (this is proper term for it) can have multiple steps of various type (e.g. custom script, SSH Exec, SSH deploy and many more). How this build configuration is being triggered is something different, and this is where triggers come to play.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding a Build, Snapshot, or Artifact dependency. I'm guessing you want a snapshot dependency;

> A snapshot dependency is a dependency between two build configurations
>   that allows launching builds from both build configurations in a
>   specific order and ensure they use the same sources snapshot (sources
>   revisions correspond to the same moment).
>
> When you have a number of build configurations interconnected by
>   snapshot dependencies, they form a build chain.

You can then put your tests into that target (or another one in the chain) depending upon your needs. There's really too much to put into a brief answer here. It's best if you read the [complete documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Dependencies+Setup).